# hover effect doesn't workon stacked fontawesome icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have no idea why `:hover` doesn't work on my `fontawesome` element. I want to change circle element to be red on hover. I think I tried already all possible selectors and only `.fa` react somehow (inside icon color changed, which is not the desired effect I want.)

HTML

```
    <ul class="nav__social-items">
        <li><a class="nav--links"  href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a></li>
        <li><a class="nav--links"  href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a></li>
        <li><a class="nav--links"  href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav__social-items {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3 1 0;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    @include mQ(485px){
        li {
        display: block;
        width: 20%; 
             }

    }
    .nav--links{
        margin-left: 30px;
        .fa-circle{
            color: #000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your CSS is the hover?

Comment: This rule will work `.fa-stack:hover .fa-stack-2x {
    color: #b91717;
}` and you can test it here: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the code very quickly to show an alternate way of doing it. Just hit 'run snippet' below to see if this is what you're after :)

Example with icon here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYYMJO

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background: red;
}
ul li i {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, yes it is!. But finally I did it in a totally different way by remowving some of fontawesome <i> and just style fa-facebook by giving this border-radius 50% and style that

Comment: Great news! Glad you have it working. Would you mind up voting my answer or marking it as correct please? Thanks Dorota :)